# Binding in WPF usercontrol

Tags: wpf

I have WPF usercontrol with some binded controls to data source, when I run the usercontrol it shows the data OK, if I add the usercontrol to window and show the window, the data are not displayed on the usercontrol??

any help will be appreciated

Comment: How are you binding to the data source?

Comment: You will need to provide more information for this question to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information you have given me I would think this would solve the problem:

When you add the UserControl set the DataContext property on the UserControl to the object you are binding to.

If that doesn't solve it write some more information about your problem in the question. Cool.

Comment: Also, check the output window whether you have any data binding errors.

Comment: How useful ...I didn't know you could do that... Thanks!